# Saving a pandas dataframe in excel with utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, pandas, encode

Simply want to set the encoding of an excel workbook for saving data. All data is stored in a pandas dataframe.

Code below:

```
file_name = "bobs_burgers"

with pd.ExcelWriter(r".\Exported_data\{file_name}.xlsx".format(file_name = file_name),
                        engine="xlsxwriter",
                        options={'encoding':'utf-8'}) as writer:

data_table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "characters", index = False)
```

I receive the error below

> TypeError: Workbook.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Using google to search for this, I have found that the majority of comments about encoding using ExcelWriter always has input of `options`.

How to set the encode to `utf-8` for exported pandas tables?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ExcelWriter documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) from pandas version 2 the `**kwargs` was removed from this class. So in order to pass `options` to ExcelWriter, you need to pass it to `engine_kwargs` as a key like this :

```
engine_kwargs = {'options':{'encoding':'utf-8'}}
```

Here is the modified version of your code :

```
file_name = "bobs_burgers"

with pd.ExcelWriter(r".\Exported_data\{file_name}.xlsx".format(file_name = file_name),
                        engine="xlsxwriter",
                        engine_kwargs = {'options':{'encoding':'utf-8'}}) as writer:

data_table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "characters", index = False)
```